# How to update a sharepoint lookup column using a grid?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have an Employee list which has 2 columns(department and manager) which are lookup columns. I need code to update these lookup columns when a new user registers. (Though the other columns are being updated in the list)

The following is the code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sp13appstoredev.xyz.com/sites/DevApps/TrainingSite/"))
    {
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees");
        clientContext.Load(oList);
        ListItemCreationInformation itemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem myItem = oList.AddItem(itemInfo);
        myItem["Title"] = txtFirstName.Text;
        myItem["Last_x0020_Name"] = txtLastName.Text;
        myItem["u5ib"] = txtAge.Text;
        myItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        //FieldLookupValue lookUpDepartment = new FieldLookupValue();
        //myItem["Department"] = lookUpDepartment as FieldLookupValue;
        //FieldLookupValue lookUpManager = new FieldLookupValue();
        //myItem["Manager"] = lookUpManager as FieldLookupValue;
        myItem["Gender"] = radioBtnGender.Text;
        myItem["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
        myItem.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

I commented the lookup column lines to check if the other columns are being updated in the list.

Kindly help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better solution :

```
            //Department column
            FieldLookupValue deptItem = new FieldLookupValue();
            deptItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListDepartment.SelectedValue);
            myItem["Department"] = deptItem;
            myItem.Update();

            //Manager column
            FieldLookupValue managerItem = new FieldLookupValue();
            managerItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListManager.SelectedValue);
            myItem["Manager"] = managerItem;
            myItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following lines worked :

```
myItem["Department"] = 1; 

myItem["Manager"] = 1;
```

I also had to set the parent list as ID (earlier it was only title)